# Is there a more secure API to authenticate & issue JWT Token without exposing Username & password in Thingsboard?

Tags: jwt, thingsboard

Our project setup is like this,
A Mobile Phone has an APP to post telemetry data to Thingsboard server.

Before posting, we have to authorize the user using JWT Token.
So, to obtain the token in first place, we need to make a following URL call,
https://TB Server Host Address/api/auth/login along with "Username" & "Password" in the body.

While making the HTTPS request, Mobile Phone has already made a secure connection with Thingsboard server in background and the whole URL is sent encrypted to Thingsboard server.

My concern is that, at Thingboard Server side, it decrypts the URL to read "Username" & "Password" and send a reply with JWT Token if they are valid user credentials and could also be keeping the logs. So, anyone with these log files have the "Username" & "Password" of the users.

Here is my main question, Is there a more secure API to authenticate & issue JWT Token without exposing Username & password in Thingsboard?

Your help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You'll need to ask someone at thingsboard whether they log user names and passwords. So far you are guessing.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because only the service provider can answer this.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yes, I am just exploring the possibilities to make secure calls between mobile & Thingsboard server.

Comment: When I asked the question "Do we have to specify Username & pwd to issue JWT token? Are there any alternative?" to Thingsboard, he replied like "Definitely, it is not the best solution to pass the Username & pwd via URL. Just and easy way, but not the best one for sure." They wouldn't share further details.

Comment: You could try using the OAUTH2 api in order to issue JWT but this requires a separate authetication service, however, its the only alternative that I can think of.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your suggestions. Will try out.